# Creating/Removing a symbolic link when a USB device connects/disconnects

Tags: usb, symlink, matlab, arduino

I'm working with an Arduino board and Matlab under Linux. Matlab, unfortunately, doesn't recognize the Arduino board when is connected *unless* I create a symbolic link to the Arduino board in `/dev` by:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyUSBx
```

Where `x` is a number and `ttyACM0` is the device associated to the Arduino board. I have to run this line every time I want to work with the Arduino and Matlab. So, my question is pretty simple: Is it possible to automatically create this symbolic link exactly when the Arduino board is connected and remove it when disconnected?

Comment: Have you tried [adding a `udev` rule](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Writing_udev_rules)?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm going to google it out.

Comment: Read the link in my comment...

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), the program that creates entries in `/dev` based on connected hardware. The following rule creates a symbolic link `/dev/ttyUSB9` for the first `ttyACM` device that is plugged in:

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB9"
```

Make it `KERNEL=="ttyACM0"` if you want the rule to apply to `ttyACM0` only (it won't make any difference unless you have multiple boards).

Run `udevadm trigger ttyACM0` to reapply the rules to the `ttyACM0` (or unplug the device and plug it back in).